# Group DB results by Date in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

i have a table that contains the following data :

```
+--------|-----------|-------------+
|  id    |  date     |   total     |
|--------|-----------|-------------|
|   1    | 2016-01-01|    10       |
|--------|-----------|-------------|
|   2    | 2016-01-01|    20       |
|--------|-----------|-------------|
|   3    | 2016-01-02|    25       |
+----------------------------------+
```

I am trying to get the following results:

```
Date : 2016-01-01 | Total : 30
Date : 2016-01-02 | Total : 25
```

And if another date gets added it will display aswell.
It must just provide the date and the total sum for that date.

This is what i have tried and it prints out every date along with each total , instead of 1 date with the main total of all for that day.

```
    $data = DB::table('records')
       ->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as total'), 'id', 'date')                      
       ->where('date', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
       ->groupBy('date')
       ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
       ->get();
```

THEN

```
foreach($data as $row){

                                    echo $row->date . "<br>";
                                    echo $row->total;

                                };
```

Comment: Do you have a typo or you forgot an apostrophe on select `date'` which should be `'date'`

Comment: what is the probleme?

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja , if you look below where Drown has tried to help , i am trying to echo out the date along with the total amount for that day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the date is actually datetime, I've made a new query for this which will group by date (Down to the day) and get total in a single query. It's not very Eloquent, but after some research I've figured this is probably the easiest way to do it in a single go.

```
$data = DB::table('records')
    ->select(DB::raw('date, SUM(total) as total'))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(date)'))
    ->get();

    return var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the data that you want :

```
 $data = DB::table('records')
    ->select(DB::raw('date, SUM(total) as total'))
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->get();
```

Example output (with my own data for testing) :

```
[
  {
    "date": "2016-09-17",
    "total": "30"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-09-18",
    "total": "23"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-09-19",
    "total": "593"
  }
]
```

Comment: thank you this works on its own, but how do i couple this with the other DB::raw() query for the total, as it throws out an error when i try do both.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the `SUM(total)` part, is this what you need?

Comment: yes i need both as i can do them separatly , but not together, thanks for the help but your example above however does not work.

Comment: What's the error? I've tried this and it works fine with your data when returning a JSON response: [{"date":"2016-01-01","total":"30"},{"date":"2016-01-02","total":"25"}]

Comment: @Daelune , im trying to return it in a foreach loop

Comment: You can use the foreach loop you posted originally to return the data from the query above :)

Comment: @Daelune , thanks , but that is what i have been trying. It returns the results but does not group them by date , so i get each result in the table with there value.

Comment: Is your date a date instance or datetime? The only reason I can see this not working is if you have the time with the date, since then the two dates would be ungrouped if they were on the same day.

Comment: @Daelune , yes they are datetime, what could i do to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Matt In your question it wasn't clear that it was a dateime, my code will only work for a date field without the time.